# What is the shell command to tell me how many users there are on the system with a certain first name and whose username starts with a 'b'?

Tags: command-line

I have managed to get the total number of users on the system with this:

```
$ getent passwd | wc -l
```

I need the number of users on the system with a certain first name (for example 'Josh') and whose usernames start with a 'b'. How? I don't know the syntax for this.

Comment: Are you use all users have proper stanza as user name?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried searching the Internet for the syntax, but couldn't figure it out. I don't know what a stanza is.

Comment: The stanza = comment for user, 5 field in the lines you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
getent passwd|awk -F: '$5 ~ /^Josh([ ,.]|$)/ && $1 ~ /^b/'|wc -l
```

Comment: @pLumo, unfortunately this will include also Joshua, which is not the OP intention

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you for the suggestion, will "steal" it :)